# What is this picture together telling?

Tags: visual

The drawing below is telling something. What does it make together? Can you guess?

[image]

Sorry for bad drawing :) .

All the best.

Comment: The last 2 appear to be rot13(GRNPURE)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

> Help, I shrunk my teacher. ("Help eye shrunk my tea chair.")
> (It's the title of a movie from 2015.)